# Dagger choosing the no-argument constructor, despite a different constructor being annotated @Inject

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm following along with the Dagger ATM tutorial online and have hit issues at the end of the page: https://dagger.dev/tutorial/03-first-command

I've dumped all of the code below for ease of reference but essentially what I understand to be happening is the Command and CommandRouter instances are being injected into the DaggerCommandRouterFactory but no matter what I do the no-parameter constructor for CommandRouter is being used - the compiler isn't happy if I leave it out, so I had two constructors and only injected the one I needed, but it was STILL calling the no-parameter constructor!

I came across the following article online (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190622), which suggests that IntelliJ is caching aspects of the previous builds and I guess within that is the annotation injecting the no-parameter constructor but I'm a bit stuck on how to rectify it.

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Command {
    String key();
    Status handleInput(List<String> input);

    enum Status {
        INVALID,
        HANDLED
    }
}
```

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;

public final class HelloWorldCommand implements Command {
    @Inject
    HelloWorldCommand(){};

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @Override
    public Status handleInput(List<String> input) {
        System.out.println(input.size());
        if (!input.isEmpty())
            return Status.INVALID;
        System.out.println("world!");
        return Status.HANDLED;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import ATM.Command.Status;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class CommandRouter {
    private final Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();

    @Inject
    CommandRouter(HelloWorldCommand helloWorldCommand){
        System.out.println("HelloWorldCommand Constructor");
        commands.put(helloWorldCommand.key(), helloWorldCommand);
    }

    CommandRouter(){
        System.out.println("No Parameter Constructor");
    }

    Status route(String input) {
        List<String> splitInput = split(input);
        if (splitInput.isEmpty()) {
            return invalidCommand(input);
        }

        String commandKey = splitInput.get(0);
        Command command = commands.get(commandKey);

        if (command == null) {
            return invalidCommand(input);
        }

        Status status = command.handleInput(splitInput.subList(1, splitInput.size()));

        if (status == Status.INVALID){
            System.out.println(commandKey + ": invalid arguments");
        }

        return status;
    }

    private Status invalidCommand(String input) {
        System.out.println(String.format("couldn't understand \"%s\". please try again.", input));
        return Status.INVALID;
    }

    private List<String> split(String input) {
        List<String> tokens = List.of(input.split(" "));
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

```
import dagger.Component;

@Component
public interface CommandRouterFactory {
    CommandRouter router();
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommandLineATM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        CommandRouterFactory commandRouterFactory = DaggerCommandRouterFactory.create();
        CommandRouter commandRouter = commandRouterFactory.router();

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            commandRouter.route(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would still be interesting to hear thoughts on this but, just to say, this has resolved itself now, it's injecting the right constructor and I've been able to completely remove the no-parameter constructor without issue. I did try rebuilding the project in IntelliJ, which might have worked (but didn't look like it had at the time I did it), or maybe it was just a case of leaving it a while, which isn't very useful!

Comment: Yes, this is really annoying. You need to click "Clean Project" from time to time. That is the only way for now. If you see something broken that does not make sense to be broken or you can't understand it - first "Clean" - investigate second :)